# Using Ocamlbuild plugins with Oasis

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, oasis

What is the proper way to integrate Ocamlbuild plugins like [Ocamlbuild-protoc](https://github.com/Khady/ocamlbuild-protoc) into a project managed by Oasis? I know how to manually edit `myocamlbuild.ml` to invoke the plugin, but that's not enough, because the proper tags have not been set. According to this particular plugin docs, it needs to be invoked with the following command, but I don't know how to do it in Oasis:

`ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -plugin-tag "package(ocamlbuild_protoc)" target.native`

Or is there maybe builtin support for Ocamlbuild plugins in Oasis that I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your `_oasis` file (outside any section) the line `AlphaFeatures: ocamlbuild_more_args` and `XOCamlbuildExtraArgs: "-plugin-tag 'package(ocamlbuild_protoc)'"`.